# ImportError at / cannot import name 'register_new_org_view' from 'users.views' (/home/ubuntu/xyz/users/views.py)

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, gunicorn

I am having trouble with my gunicorn, nginx deployed django application.
Everything runs smoothly on my local development and `python manage.py check` does not throw any errors. However, as soon as I deploy my application to my server this error is thrown:`ImportError at / cannot import name 'register_new_org_view' from 'users.views' (/home/ubuntu/xyz/users/views.py)`

I have defined the view and import it correctly... other views from other apps are working perfectly fine... what can be the reason?

Thank you so much for your help!

Update1: Project Tree/Structure:

```
xyz_Django
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── xyz_django_env
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── landingpage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── organization
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── overview
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── custom_HTML_calendar.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── overview_helper.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── testing_file.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
├── slack_application
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── slack_application_helpers.py
│   ├── slack_notifications.py
│   ├── slack_notifications_daily_afternoon.py
│   ├── slack_notifications_daily_morning.py
│   ├── slack_notifications_weekly_friday.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── templates
│   ├── account
│   └── socialaccount
└── users
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── adapter.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    ├── tests.py
    ├── tokens.py
    ├── user_automation_on_submission.py
    ├── user_automations_daily_update.py
    └── views.py
```

Comment: well you have to provide us with project's full directory tree

Comment: @quqa123 see updated post. thank you!

Comment: okay so the structure is correct (kind of) please show users/views.py or at least the part where "register_new_org_view" is declared